# How can I check if an user is superuser in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-users

I'm listing registered users on a [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) page and I'm trying to show if user is superuser or not.

My main user is created with `python manage.py createsuperuser` command and I'm sure it is a superuser beacuse I've checked from admin panel too.

When I try to print if it is superuser or not my code always shows a `False` output. Here are my codes:

**views.py**

```py
@method_decorator(staff_member_required, name='dispatch')
class Uyeler(ListView):
    model = User
    paginate_by = 40
    ordering = ['-pk']
    template_name = "panel/uyeler.html"
```

and in template file:

```html
{% for obj in object_list %} 
  {% if obj.is_superuser %}
    SuperUser 
  {% else %}
    Not SuperUser {{ obj.is_superuser }}
  {% endif %}
    
{% endfor %}
```

And my html output is "**Not SuperUser False**" for all users including my superuser account. Any ideas?

Comment: No change. I'm printing it just for information anyway.

Comment: What does "admin pannel" say about superuser value ?

Comment: in admin panel superuser box is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried in my code and it's working maybe there's issue in your data this is how my code looks like

**views.py**

```py
def user_detail(request):
  user_detail = CustomUser.objects.filter(id=id)
  return(request,'user_datail.html',{'user_detail':user_detail})
```

**user_datail.html**

```html
{% for i in user_detail %}
  {% if i.is_superuser %}
     <td class="text-center"><span class="btn btn-success">You</span> 
     </td>
  {% else %}
    <td class="text-center"><span class="btn btn-info">Agent</span> 
    </td>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**output**

[image: view image]

Answer (score 19):

This is my `views.py`, for showing current user accounts

````py
@login_required
def account(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser: # just using request.user attributes
        accounts = get_user_model().objects.all()```
````